# Derivative of this function $2^{5x^{2}}$?

Tags: calculus

Can I have some help with this derivative? Thanks very much. I got up to $e^{5x^{2}}\ln 2.(10x\ln 2)$ except it's the wrong answer.

Comment: Did you mean $e^{5x^2\ln2}(10x\ln2)$?

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have to differentiate a function of the form $$y=u^v$$ where both $u,v$ are functions of the independent variable $x.$ Then take the logarithms of both sides. $$\ln y=v\ln u.$$ Then differentiate. Good luck.